# CSS will not change link color. Not sure why

Tags: css

My CSS has the following code for links for the whole website:

```
#mainpanecontent A:link {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #6a0a0a; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
```

I want to change a header that is also a link to be a different color using the code below but it doesn't enforce it. My code is inside a div that uses the "mainpanecontent" :

**Header code**

```
.contact
 {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
padding-left: 50px;
background-position: 25px 14px;
padding-top: 13px;


}

.contact a:link, .contact a:visited
{

color: #1F507F;

}


.contact a:hover
{

color: #1F507F;


}
.contact a:active
{

color: #1F507F;


}
```

Answer (score 4):

`#mainpanecontent A:link` has a higher specificity than any of your `.contact a:something`s. The best way to solve this is probably to give your header an ID and use that. If you can’t, and it’s only in `#maincontent`, `#maincontent` will suffice, even if it’s not entirely appropriate. (Depends on the situation.)

```css
#mainpanecontent .contact a:link {
    color: #1f507f;
}
```

Also, just drop the `:link`, especially if you’re going to specify the same thing for all of them. (The only consideration there, `<a name>`, isn’t used these days.)

Comment: Wow. I did not think about doing that and thank you for the explanation. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has a system of priority for handling what gets what tags :: Give [this a read](http://hungred.com/useful-information/css-priority-order-tips-tricks/)

Here is a simple rewrite of your code that should work :)

*Everything higher on the list should overwrite things lower of the list of the same type*

```
.contact a:active
{

color: #1F507F;


}
.contact a:hover
{

color: #1F507F;


}

.contact a:link, .contact a:visited
{

color: #1F507F;

}


 .contact
 {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
padding-left: 50px;
background-position: 25px 14px;
padding-top: 13px;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

CSS Rules are sometimes not enforced due to how explicit the previous rule was, in the rule you list above it references an ID, which is more explicit than a class.

The other issue of course can be that your "overrides" are defined BEFORE the other rule, therefore they are overwritten.

In the first case you can use `!important` to force the override of the rule.

e.g.

```
.contact
{
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-position: 25px 14px;
  padding-top: 13px;
}

.contact a {
  color: #1F507F !important;
}
```

Note I removed the other rules, because you are only setting the link color to the same color in each case, so there's no need to define the pseudo-classes `:hover`, `:active` etc. with the same constant.

Comment: Please don’t use `!important`. It only works on one level and always ends in sadness.